# Passing function arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

In the below code, how can I pass `obj` value to save token function.

```
var token;
var obj = {"name":"xyz"}
OAuth2.Password.getToken({
  username: 'username',
  password: 'password' 
}, saveToken);

// Save the access token
function saveToken(error, result) {
  if (error) { console.log('Access Token Error', error.message); }
  token = OAuth2.AccessToken.create(result);
});
```

Comment: What is `obj` supposed to do inside of `saveToken`? For that matter, your use of the non-function-variable `token` implies that you should be also be able to use `obj` inside `saveToken` without having to pass it in (though it usually is better to modularize such dependencies via either object functions or just closures; makes dependency injection and thus testing and code interoperation much easier).

Comment: The way it's written right now you don't *need* to.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use bind()?

```
saveToken.bind(obj);
```

I didn't fully understood what do you need.